# How to access shared folders

Tags: vpn, powershell, sftp, winscp

I have VPN tunnel between two computers and through WinSCP (or any other SFTP client) I can access shared folders. Is it possible to access them outside the SFTP client (in the OS)? I have to access them with powershell script. Thank you

Comment: If you have a VPN tunnel, you could just map the share using CIFS or NFS.

Answer (score 0):

The OS won't natively support functions such as mapping a drive to an sftp share.

You can use a third party tool to map drives to sftp servers (eg [Expandrive](http://www.expandrive.com/) or [Webdrive](http://www.webdrive.com/)).

In PowerShell, you can either use third party cmdlets, such as ActiveSockets or NetCmdlets.

Otherwise, I can only think of using PowerShell with the *Invoke-Item* CmdLet to call Cygwin's sftp.exe or some other Windows sftp client.

Comment: Thank you, Adam. I prefer no third party solution. The NetCmdlets looks great, but it's sad that I missed the christmas free version and I don't have time to wait while our company buy license. Is it possible to do it with IIS? I have windows 2003 server and IIS6, but I am afraid that IIS6 doesn't support SFTP.

Comment: No, IIS doesn't add any support for SFTP, I'm afraid.  You could use Cygwin to provide an ssh/sftp service running on Windows.  Otherwise, Netcmdlets has a free trial version, which might work for you whilst you wait for corporate accounting to pay for the full version.